# Hierarchical Query alias not working Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following query

```
 Select item_number, parent_item_number, item_lable, level
   From ( -- inner query
          Select tech_key as item_number, 
                 unit_parent as parent_item_number,
                 Nvl2 (ltrim (rtrim(unit_kind) || unit_serial_number)),
                 Ltrim (rtrim (unit_kind || ' ' || unit_serial_number)) || nvl2 (unit_name, ' - ' || ltrim (rtrim (unit_name)), ''),
                 Ltrim (rtrim (unit_name) as item_lable
            From v_glb_unit) --end of inner query
  Where parent_item_number is not null 
  start with parent_item_number =1234
Connect by prior item_number = parent_item_number 
  order by level asc
```

It works as expected on Oracle 10g Windows, but having upgraded the database to Oracle 11g Linux - it is no longer working.

It does not recognize the parent_item_number and item_number aliases, and throws an ORA -00904.

It is worth noting that without the usage of aliases it works, however this is not an option - the inner query is dynamic.

*edit*

I will add that v_glb_unit is a symbol and the view is over a dblink.

Comment: Well, you've gone through great lengths to make your query hard to read, but it seems to be fine. I can't imagine that 11G has this issue (I've not encountered it during our migration), but if you think it does, maybe file a bug report.

Comment: Yea, I am sorry - using a smartphone to copy the code... I am not sure what causes this issue, I just know that it worked on our previous database

Comment: What version of 11g?  Have you applied the terminal patchset?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Relese 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: I am not sure about the patchset, I need to ask the dba.

Comment: How come you are just passing a single expression in NVL2 function?

Comment: I am not, I am passing two...